# Después de enviar formulario hace validación (error)

Tags: javascript, formularios, validación, google-apps-script

Tengo un formulario HTML en Apps Script con validación `class="needs-validation"`, todo funciona correctamente.
El form tiene un botón reset, que funciona correctamente
`<button id="B_Borrar_Form" type="reset"  class="btn btn-secondary" style="float: right;">Borrar Datos</button>`

El form tiene un botón que se llama desde JavaScript y ejecuta un función para guardar datos (Funciona)

```html
<button id="G_C" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Guardar Nuevo Colectivo</button>
```

Al final llama una función para resetear el formulario

```
function limpiarFormulario(miform) {
        document.getElementById(miform).reset();
      }
```

El problema es que después de limpiar el formulario, este queda como si se hubiera validado

[image: Formulario después de guardar]

```js
document.getElementById("G_C").addEventListener("click", Enviar_Colectivos) 

      function Enviar_Colectivos(){
        N_Colectivo=document.getElementById("N_Colectivo").value;
        C_Colectivo=document.getElementById("C_Colectivo").value;
        T_Colectivo=document.getElementById("T_Colectivo").value;
        M_Colectivo=document.getElementById("M_Colectivo").value;
        N_Objetivos=document.getElementById("N_Objetivos").value;
        O1_Colectivo=document.getElementById("O1_Colectivo").value;
        O2_Colectivo=document.getElementById("O2_Colectivo").value;
        O3_Colectivo=document.getElementById("O3_Colectivo").value;
        O4_Colectivo=document.getElementById("O4_Colectivo").value;
        google.script.run.Grabar_Colectivo(N_Colectivo,C_Colectivo,T_Colectivo,M_Colectivo,N_Objetivos,O1_Colectivo,O3_Colectivo,O3_Colectivo,O4_Colectivo);

        limpiarFormulario("Colectivo");
        alert ("El Colectivo ha sido guardado correctamente");
      }

      function limpiarFormulario(miform) {
        document.getElementById(miform).reset();
      }
```

```html
 <form id="Colectivo" class="needs-validation" novalidate>

            <div class="row g-2">
                <div class="col-md">
                    <div class="mt-3 form-floating">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="N_Colectivo" required/>
                        <label> Escribe el Nombre del Colectivo</label>
                        <div class ="valid-feedback">
                            Correcto
                        </div>
                        <div class ="invalid-feedback"> 
                            Es necesario Ingresar el nombre del colectivo
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mt-3 form-floating">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="T_Colectivo" required/>
                        <label>Teléfono de contacto</label>
                        <div class ="valid-feedback"> 
                            Correcto
                        </div>
                        <div class ="invalid-feedback"> 
                            Es necesario diligenciar el numero telefonico
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md">
                    <div class="mt-3 form-floating">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="C_Colectivo" required/>
                        <label class="form-label">Persona de contacto</label>
                        <div class ="valid-feedback"> 
                            Correcto
                        </div>
                        <div class ="invalid-feedback"> 
                            Es necesario diligenciar el nombre de la persona
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mt-3 form-floating">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="M_Colectivo" required/>
                        <label>Correo Electrónico</label>
                        <div class ="valid-feedback"> 
                            Correcto
                        </div>
                        <div class ="invalid-feedback"> 
                            Es necesario diligenciar un correo electrónico válido
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mt-3 form-floating">
                        <select
                        id="N_Objetivos"
                        class="form-select"
                        required
                        onchange="mostrar_cajas()"
                        >
                        <option selected></option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        </select>
                        <label>Elige el número de objetivos</label>
                        <div class ="valid-feedback"> 
                            Correcto
                        </div>
                        <div class ="invalid-feedback"> 
                            Es necesario elegir el numero de objetivos
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row g-2 mt-3">
                <div class="col-md">
                    <div id="O1" hidden  class="mb-3 form-floating" >
                        <textarea
                        class="form-control"
                        id="O1_Colectivo"
                        style="height: 100px"
                        required
                        ></textarea>
                        <label>Objetivo # 1</label>
                        <div class ="valid-feedback"> 
                            Correcto
                        </div>
                        <div class ="invalid-feedback"> 
                            Es necesario diligenciar el objetivo
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="O3" hidden class="mb-3 form-floating" >
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="O3_Colectivo" style="height: 100px" required></textarea>
                        <label>Objetivo # 3</label>
                        <div class ="valid-feedback"> 
                            Correcto
                        </div>
                        <div class ="invalid-feedback"> 
                            Es necesario diligenciar el objetivo
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md">
                    <div id="O2" hidden class="mb-3 form-floating" >
                        <textarea
                        class="form-control"
                        id="O2_Colectivo"
                        style="height: 100px"
                        required
                        ></textarea>
                        <label>Objetivo # 2</label>
                        <div class ="valid-feedback"> 
                            Correcto
                        </div>
                        <div class ="invalid-feedback"> 
                            Es necesario diligenciar el objetivo
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="O4" hidden class="mb-3 form-floating" >
                        <textarea
                        class="form-control"
                        id="O4_Colectivo"
                        style="height: 100px"
                        required
                        ></textarea>
                        <label>Objetivo # 4</label>
                        <div class ="valid-feedback"> 
                            Correcto
                        </div>
                        <div class ="invalid-feedback"> 
                            Es necesario diligenciar el objetivo
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- https://www.neoguias.com/mostrar-ocultar-elementos-html/   -->

          <div class="row g-2 border border-primary align-items-center ">

          <div class="col-md border border-secondary text-right">
                <button id="B_Borrar_Form" type="reset"  class="btn btn-secondary" style="float: right;">Borrar Datos</button>
          </div>


            <div class="col-md  border border-secondary text-center">
                  <button id="G_C" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Guardar Nuevo Colectivo</button>
            </div>
          </div>


      </form>
```

```js
var rutaWeb = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
const Libro = SpreadsheetApp.openById("10cJ4HedtvXgLP_gOoeTh4AsAQNwrBaTprAmft9Iy6Vc")
const Hoja_Colectivo = Libro.getSheetByName("Colectivos") 

function doGet(e) {
  var page = e.parameter.p || "App";
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(page).evaluate(); 
  }

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
};

//Guardar Colectivos
function Grabar_Colectivo(N_Colectivo,C_Colectivo,T_Colectivo,M_Colectivo,N_Objetivos,O1_Colectivo,O3_Colectivo,O3_Colectivo,O4_Colectivo) {
  //const Libro = SpreadsheetApp.openById("10cJ4HedtvXgLP_gOoeTh4AsAQNwrBaTprAmft9Iy6Vc")
  //const Hoja_Colectivo = Libro.getSheetByName("Colectivos") 

  var Fila_Id = Hoja_Colectivo.getLastRow()
  var Celda_N_O = "A"+Fila_Id
  var New_Id = Hoja_Colectivo.getRange(Celda_N_O).getValue()
  
  //verificar si la Celda_N_O es un numero o es texto
  if (isNaN(New_Id)){ 
    var New_Id = 1
  } else {
    var New_Id = Hoja_Colectivo.getRange(Celda_N_O).getValue()+1
  }
 
  Hoja_Colectivo.appendRow([New_Id,N_Colectivo,C_Colectivo,T_Colectivo,M_Colectivo,N_Objetivos,O1_Colectivo,O3_Colectivo,O3_Colectivo,O4_Colectivo])
  
}
```

Comment: ¿Y si le quitas la clase `class="needs-validation"` **antes** del reset() y luego la vuelves a poner?

Comment: Agrega un [mcve] (incluye el  html/css/javascript del form, indica el framework que estas usando Bootstrap?)

Comment: No funciono con 
```function limpiarFormulario(miform) {
        document.getElementById(miform).classList.remove("needs-validation")
        document.getElementById(miform).reset();
      }```

Comment: Pues será que son campos `required` supongo... quizás podrias probar quitando el `required` (tal como has hecho con la clase, pero tambien con el required) y despues del reset lo vuelves a poner. A ver si hay suerte.

Comment: Falta `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">` o el que corresponda, si pones el código en Stack Snippet deberías comentar la línea `google.script.run` ya que no funcionaría además de agregar las funciones del lado del cliente como mostrar_cajas... véase [mcve].

Comment: lo del `google.script.run` funciona correctamente, tambien tengo el link a bootstrap, es más, todo funciona correctamente... y guarda, el problema es que después de guardar el formulario queda con validación, y como está vacío, todo queda en rojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás usando Bootstrap 5, retira la clase `was-validated` del elemento form. Una forma de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```javascript
document.querySelector('form').classList.remove('was-validated');
```

Lo anterior usualmente se coloca en un callback del evento submit del elemento form que corresponda luego de haber verificado que el elemento form sea válido.

Nota: El código del Stack Snippet está incompleto y tiene varios problemas:

1. Se está asignando un event listener tipo click al elemento button tipo submit. Usualmente lo que se hace es usar un event listener tipo submit al elemento form.
2. El callback de del evento anterior incluye un google.script.run y después de este la confirmación de que se envió correctamente, lo cual es incorrecto porque google.script.run es asíncrono y en caso de falla se le habría mostrado al usuario una confirmación de envío correcto siendo que ha ocurrido un error. Debería utilizarse los métodos withSuccessHandler y withFailureHandler de google.script.run para controlar lo que se hace en caso de éxito y/o falla de llamada a la función del lado del servidor.
3. Aparentemente se está usando Bootstrap, este requiere de la asignación de la clase `.was-validated` al elemento form pero el código no incluye esto.
4. No se incluye el código para agregar la hoja de estilos de Bootstrap.

La documentación de Bootstrap cuenta con varios ejemplos sobre cómo realizar la validación de formularios.

Comment: Continua mostrando la validación con los campos resaltados en rojo

Comment: Es necesario el `google.script.run`, pues es la conexión para guardar la información

Comment: `google.script.run` no es soportado por Stack Snippet, sólo por Google Apps Script, la idea de quitarlo en la respuesta es para que Stack Snippet pueda ejecutar el código y mostrar el funcionación de los estilos usados en la validación.

Comment: @ElkinDelgado Edité mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información, trataré de corregir con ello.